# Clear global environment, keep environments created by new.env()

Tags: r

In order to keep global environment clean, I create some environments with "`new.env()`". Is it possible to delete all objects in global environment, but keep all environment created with "`new.env()`" ? .

**What I have tried so far:**

`rm(list=ls())`

- Removes all objects in "global.env" including environments created with "`new.env()`".

`rm(list = ls()[! ls() %in% c("a")])`

- Removes all objects but keep the ones specified. Problem here is that I want to avoid adding the environment names in case they would either change or grow in amount.

**Wanted behaviour:**

Remove should delete all objects from "global.env" but keep all environments created with "`new.env()`".

Comment: You can create new environment that starts with `.` and then use `all.names` argument in `ls`.

Comment: I doubt you could do exactly what you're saying. But I think we can do what you want.  It seems you want to keep environments but remove everything else.  `ls.str(mode = "environment")` will give you a list of the current environments that are in your current environment but it won't know if you created them by calling new.env or something else.

Answer (score 0):

We can use:

```
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE)[sapply(mget(ls(all=TRUE)), function(x) !is.environment(x))])
```

Test this in a new empty environment:

```
s<-9
iris1<-iris[1:24,]
e2<-new.env()
e3<-new.env()
e4<-new.env()
```

Next we remove anything that isn't an environment(the flaw in this is that we're not testing for an environment created specifically by `new.env` but any "object" that is an environment within `.Globalenv`).
Test it:

```
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE)[sapply(mget(ls(all=TRUE)), function(x) !is.environment(x))])
```

Leaves you with only environments.

Comment: Answers should make sure they actually answer the question and work. Did you do that? then there is no need to "try". also, you should elaborate why this answer works.

Comment: It works. I just like to use the word "try". I'll edit all the same.